# Simple Game Calculator - Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple calculator for a game I've been playing a lot lately, but for some reason I can't get it to output my variable. I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

No idea why as I had this working perfectly a couple days ago but since I've added a few features this has been the result.

If someone can see where I've made a mistake that'd be a life saver, I've been looking for it for the past 2 days. So I thought I'd get a "second" set of eyes.

Thanks,
Matt.

```js
updateSlider();

function updateSlider() {
  var P1H = parseInt(document.getElementById("P1H").value);
  var P1S = parseInt(document.getElementById("P1S").value);

  document.getElementById('P1H_value').innerHTML = P1H;
  document.getElementById('P1S_value').innerHTML = P1S;


  var P2H = parseInt(document.getElementById("P2H").value);
  var P2S = parseInt(document.getElementById("P2S").value);

  document.getElementById('P2H_value').innerHTML = P2H;
  document.getElementById('P2S_value').innerHTML = P2S;

  var P3H = parseInt(document.getElementById("P3H").value);
  var P3S = parseInt(document.getElementById("P3S").value);

  document.getElementById('P3H_value').innerHTML = P3H;
  document.getElementById('P3S_value').innerHTML = P3S;

  var P4H = parseInt(document.getElementById("P4H").value);
  var P4S = parseInt(document.getElementById("P4S").value);

  document.getElementById('P4H_value').innerHTML = P4H;
  document.getElementById('P4S_value').innerHTML = P4S;

  var EH = parseInt(document.getElementById("EH").value);

  if (document.getElementById('hcheck1').checked) {
    var enemies_health = 1;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('hcheck2').checked) {
    var enemies_health = 1.5;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('hcheck3').checked) {
    var enemies_health = 2;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('hcheck4').checked) {
    var enemies_health = 2.5;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('hcheck5').checked) {
    var enemies_health = 3;
  }

  document.getElementById('EH_value').innerHTML = EH;
  document.getElementById('enemies_health_value').innerHTML = enemies_health;
  document.getElementById('enemies_sheild_value').innerHTML = enemies_sheild;

  var P1R = (P1H + P1S) / 2;

  var P2R = (P2H + P2S) / 2;

  var P3R = (P3H + P3S) / 2;

  var P4R = (P4H + P4S) / 2;

  var teamR = (P1R + P2R + P3R + P4R);

  var winChance = (teamR / EH) * enemies_health;

  document.getElementById('winChance_value').innerHTML = winChance;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

#winChance {
  width: 100%;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 95%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2.5%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  appearance: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="winChance">
  <h1 align="center">Fire Fight Win Chance</h1>
  <h2 align="center" id="winChance_value"></h2>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h1>Enemy Heads</h1>
  <h2 align="center">Heads:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="EH_value">1</h3>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" class="slider" id="EH" oninput="updateSlider();">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 align="center">Avg Health:</h3>

        <label class="container">100
      <input type="radio" id="hcheck1" name="enemy_health" value="100" onclick="updateSlider();" checked>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">75
      <input type="radio" id="hcheck2" name="enemy_health" value="75" onclick="updateSlider();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">50
      <input type="radio" id="hcheck3" name="enemy_health" value="50" onclick="updateSlider();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">25
      <input type="radio" id="hcheck4" name="enemy_health" value="25" onclick="updateSlider();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">1
      <input type="radio" id="hcheck5" name="enemy_health" value="1" onclick="updateSlider();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

      </td>
      <td>
        <h3 align="center">Avg Sheild:</h3>

        <label class="container">100
      <input type="radio" name="enemy_sheild" value="100">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">75
      <input type="radio" name="enemy_sheild" value="75">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">50
      <input type="radio" name="enemy_sheild" value="50">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">25
      <input type="radio" name="enemy_sheild" value="25">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

        <label class="container">0
      <input type="radio" name="enemy_sheild" value="0" checked>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h1>Player 1</h1>

  <h2 align="center">Health:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P1H_value">100</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="P1H" oninput="updateSlider();">
  <h2 align="center">Shield:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P1S_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P1S" oninput="updateSlider();">
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h1>Player 2</h1>

  <h2 align="center">Health:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P2H_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P2H" oninput="updateSlider();">
  <h2 align="center">Shield:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P2S_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P2S" oninput="updateSlider();">
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h1>Player 3</h1>

  <h2 align="center">Health:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P3H_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P3H" oninput="updateSlider();">
  <h2 align="center">Shield:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P3S_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P3S" oninput="updateSlider();">
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h1>Player 4</h1>

  <h2 align="center">Health:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P4H_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P4H" oninput="updateSlider();">
  <h2 align="center">Shield:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P4S_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P4S" oninput="updateSlider();"> </div>
```

Comment: I see a similar but different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. It seems that the `enemies_health_value` and `enemies_sheild_value` elements don't exist in your HTML.

Comment: I agree with @showdev the problem resides here:  `document.getElementById('enemies_health_value').innerHTML = enemies_health;`
 `document.getElementById('enemies_sheild_value').innerHTML = enemies_sheild;`